# Mac Pro 5.1 (mid 2012 ) Fusion Drive (2 SSDs and 1 HDD)

Tags: ssd, mac-pro, fusion-drive, hdd, raid

I have 2 SSDs 160GB each and a 4TB Disk (all SATA) I was thinking to put them in Fusion Drive setup, will it work? how it will work?

which setup is recommended if possible? any speed benefits?

- Fusion Drive (SSD + SSD + HDD)
- Fusion Drive ((RAID 0 2xSSD) + HDD)

I know the risk of data loss if one of them fail
I have the fourth disk will be used for TimeMachine + plus other backup options

Comment: You might benefit from RAIDing the SSDs - would double the effective bus speed, which is only 3gigabit on the old cheese graters... but I'm not sure it will boot from a DIY RAID without a dedicated RAID card. I wouldn't bother with Fusion if you already have 320GB of SSD. Fusion is designed to be a kind of caching mechanism & has really been out-dated by new large SSDs.

Comment: I will be testing the raid, my idea was to have a big disk (Fusion Drive) so I can work on photos and other big files, the unused files from the OS will be moved to HDD ... that my understanding on how Fusion Drive :)

Comment: My understanding is everything lives on the HD, with commonly-used files being 'promoted' to the SSD rather than the other way round with them being 'demoted' to the HD. I also get the feeling you will either be able to achieve the 2SSD RAID **or** the fusion [1 SSD, 1 HD] but no combination that will give you 2 SSDs or the RAID as part of a Fusion. I have the same machine. I just went for a 1TB SSD & 4 4TB HDs, kept it simple ;)

Comment: Im not trying to invest in this machine as I have plans to buy new one, it lacks Thunderbolt, More ram, better GFX, USB3 ... etc ... thinking on getting a whole new machine next year, but I have this disks and I was thinking to use them

Comment: Sure - i topped mine out a couple of years ago, dual 3.46GHz 6-cores, 64GB RAM, HD 7950 & the big SSD. I haven't needed USB3 [for which I think you can get a PCI card] or Thunderbolt as yet. I'm waiting to see what the hoped-for new Mac Pro looks like next year before I make any decisions.

Comment: ok then, I will test all this when the new OS out, I will back up everything, then start test the combinations and ses how it will perform :)

Comment: Is it possible to put a PCIe 2.0 to SATA III card in that Mac Pro model?

Comment: OWC do all kinds of upgrade kits, inc 6GB/s drives directly on PCIe - https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/mac-pro/2009-2012 "The Accelsior E2 utilizes the PCIe slot in Mac Pros and PC towers, the fastest data interface available, to deliver up to 820MB/s of blistering performance. That's nearly 3x faster than an SSD equipped Mac Pro 3Gb/s drive bay, and well beyond 6Gb/s drive speeds. " I've never tried one, so idk how good they actually are.

Comment: or this one - https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/SSDPHWQT2.0/ "Sustained speeds up to 1947MB/s"